# Dart: Save file contents for use after compilation

Tags: dart

Is there a way to save the contents of another file in my Dart binary? I feel it is easier to just show what I am trying to do

**Example:**

template.txt

```
Hello, {NAME}!
```

main.dart

```dart
File file = File('template.txt');
// write code to replace {NAME} with name dynamically given from -n flag
```

Now I compile

```bash
dart compile exe main.dart -o main
```

Now I run the binary

```bash
./main -n Mark
Hello, Mark!
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing that right now?  Or do you mean that you want your compiled binary to not depend on a `template.txt` file existing in the current directory?  If so, you my [`resource_importer` package](https://pub.dev/packages/resource_importer) would let you import the contents of `template.txt` as a Dart string literal.